# startActivityForResult and window visiblility

Tags: android, android-activity, android-windowmanager

The documentation of the startActivityForResult says:

> As a special case, if you call startActivityForResult() with a requestCode >= 0 during the initial onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)/onResume() of your activity, then your window will not be displayed until a result is returned back from the started activity. This is to avoid visible flickering when redirecting to another activity.

However, I can still see the window of my first activity for a short time.
Am I missing something?

Comment: Post your code. Maybe you are doing something else that causes the activity to display.

Comment: Or you can post it as bug in google-code in Android ...